How to generate an order securely?
I would like to know if there is a way to order n members such that each member only knows their own position in the order without knowing others' positions, and this method does not rely on a trusted central entity. In other words, I hope the solution that meets these requirements is decentralized.

Two questions: does the order need to be dependent on some kind of data and / or calculation? What are the rules for the members to collude? The current question seems somewhat light on this kind of detail.

I've closed this question until detail is added, please [edit] the question.
